# Angular2 - meta tags are not taking in social media like facebook

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, angular, meta

I have statically used meta tags in index.html (Angular2). But facebook is not taking the meta tags while sharing.

```
    <meta property="og:description" content="Test description"/>
    <meta property="og:image"   content="https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Test site name"/>
    <meta property="og:title"   content="test" />
    <meta property="og:type"    content="object" />
    <meta property="og:url"     content="http://www.google.com" />
```

Anybody knows the reason?

Answer (score 1):

You said  "`statically used meta tags in index.html`" I think the issue with cache.Use [facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/),
put the URL of the page you want to share, and click "debug". It will automatically extract all the info on your meta tags and also clear the cache.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of page rendering

1. Client side and
2. Server side rendering

Now, as angular does client side rendering, meta tags are not rendered before the DOM is completely rendered.

Any kind of meta tags that are rendered by the server is recognized by *facebook* debugger but client side meta tags are not. Google is working on client side rendered meta tag crawling but is yet not perfect (as they stated in their event).

> Check your *view page source* for meta tags.

To know how to add server side rendered meta tags route specifically drop a comment.